# "checked" statement causing error on a vba macro for excel

Tags: vba, excel

So i need to add a formula to an entire column using a macro,
so far i have:

```
Range("S2:S" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(TRIM(N2)="checked",M2,IF(LEN(P2)>=60, P2, IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(R2,CONCATENATE(" ", $J$2),""))>=60,SUBSTITUTE(R2,CONCATENATE(" ", $J$2),""),R2)))"
```

Which is supposed to take several values of different cells and form a new one, the problem is that the code sends an error "Syntax Error" but if i put the formula in a cell in excel the formula works perfectly.

Any idea on what could be causing the error? i think it could be linked with how its writen and how vba reads it.

Comment: I tend to use FormulaR1C1 personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA you must double-up all the quotes inside, viz (there might be other issues, I haven't checked). I expect a google search would have solved this for you.

```
Range("S2:S" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(TRIM(N2)=""checked"",M2,IF(LEN(P2)>=60, P2, IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(R2,CONCATENATE("" "", $J$2),""""))>=60,SUBSTITUTE(R2,CONCATENATE("" "", $J$2),""""),R2)))"
```

Comment: OMG yes it was that exactly